# VMware Fusion: Failed to power on VM (macOS Big Sur M1)

Tags: vmware, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, vmware-fusion

VMWare Fusion Professional Version 12.1.2 (17964953) on macOS Big Sur (M1 chip) fails to create a virtual machine. Tried with Debian 64bit and openSUSE 64bit/32bit.
Error popup: `Failed to power on '/Users/user/Virtual Machines.localized/Debian 10.x.vmwarevm/Debian 10.x.vmx'`

When I'm trying to lunch a VM created on another Mac with VMWare Fusion 11, I'm getting the same error.

Any ideas how to debug and what could be wrong?

Comment: EDIT: From the research I've done, it seems that while you can probably get VMware fusion player 12 itself to install and run on an M1 Mac, it won't be able to run any images. If you have VMware Fusion Player 12 Intel version installed, it won't be able to run any image. [Source](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Failed-to-power-on-virtual-machine/m-p/2847343#M174122) I am getting the same exact problem and would love a resolution. I also have an M1 MacBook Pro.